# How to create an Outlook add-in in Delphi without using third party components?

Tags: delphi

How to write an Outlook add-in in Delphi without depending on any third party components. Looking for compatibility with MS Office from 2003 and all newer releases.

I see similar questions in SO but the response will always suggest to use some third-party component.

Comment: What's against using them? You're doing work that's already been done for you and it's unlikely that you'll do better or at least equally well at a lower cost, unless your time is free, of course.

Comment: You need to read the documentation for COM add-ins. Did you do that yet? I did that once. After I'd worked out what was involved, I bought the wonderful Add-in Express.

Comment: I know it is not easy and need quite some effort if you want to do it from scratch. That is the reason I was looking for some sample code so that I can build my add-in based on that. Some companies discourage use of third party components to keep licensing simple.

Answer (score 3):

To develop a Outlook Addin or interface other applications with Outlook, you need to use the Outlook Object Model.

- [Outlook Object Model Reference - Office 2003](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa221870.aspx)
- [Outlook Object Model Reference - Office 2007](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb176619.aspx)
- [Outlook Object Model Reference - Office 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb176619.aspx)

Comment: This fails to address the heart of the question. Yes it is true, one will need to use the Office object model. But that's the easy bit, the bit that anyone can do. The difficult bit is creating an add-in that will be loaded by the Office app. That involves writing and registering an in-proc COM server that implements the appropriate interfaces in the correct manner. And registering with the Office app. So this answer seems more like a comment.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a (sample) project I found which creates an add-in to outlook. This will help to understand the technology.

http://www.dimastr.com/babelfish/

Tested with Outlook 2003 and Delphi 2007

You have to register the DLL using regsvr32.exe